# Grouping with variable number of elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML in this format:

```
<wrapper>   
    <entry>
        <categories>

            <category>Ambitious</category>
            <cat_id>1928</cat_id>

            <category>Wealthy</category>
            <cat_id>262</cat_id>
            <catnotes>Extravagant</catnotes>

            <category>Royal family</category>
            <cat_id>151</cat_id>
            <catnotes>France</catnotes>

        </categories>

        <id>1</id>

    </entry>

...Multiple entries in similar format

</wrapper>
```

Each category is followed by a category id. This may or may note be followed by category notes.

**I would like to group them together with each group having a category, category id, category notes (if present) and id.**

I tried this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:template match="wrapper/entry">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
                <category-wrap>
                    <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::cat_id[1] | following-sibling::catnotes[1]"/>
                </category-wrap>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the current output

```
<entry>
   <category-wrap>
      <category>Ambitious</category>
      <cat_id>1928</cat_id>
      <catnotes>Extravagant</catnotes>
   </category-wrap>
   <category-wrap>
      <category>Wealthy</category>
      <cat_id>262</cat_id>
      <catnotes>Extravagant</catnotes>
   </category-wrap>
   <category-wrap>
      <category>Royal family</category>
      <cat_id>151</cat_id>
      <catnotes>France</catnotes>
   </category-wrap>
</entry>
```

The notes are being picked up even if they do not correspond to that category. I would like to ignore the notes if they are not there.

Also I would like the ID to be part of each group/wrapping.

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Try it first, then post again if you're having a specific problem with the implementation.

Comment: It is not clear which result you want, perhaps you need to spell out a bit more of the input and then the wanted output as well. Is the grouping/structuring already established in the input XML? Or can you have several `categories` element with the same `category` and/or `cat_id` value and you need to group them? `following-sibling::*[2][self::catnotes]` should help to select only the immediately following `catnotes` element.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k will check it out, the more I learn XSL the deeper it appears.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen Dont understand the *[2] syntax though, need to learn more, I thought it meant the second catnotes from the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 3][self::cat_id|self::catnotes]"/>
```

This wil only copy following-sibling::* (elements) which position is less then 3 and are cat_id or catnotes

Alt 2(Following your same approach) is :

```
<xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[1][self::cat_id] | following-sibling::*[2][self::catnotes]"/>
```

The problem with following-sibling::cat_id[1] is that it will find any following-sibling::cat_id and then only the first.

Comment: Thanks @Siebe, using the position less than 3 works in this use case. Now just need to add the id to each new group. Probably need to access the parent categories element and then its sibling id, will try it out.

Comment: @AmitSaxena: Success. As a tip: declare in your template match a variabel pointing to the id and then just copy that variable in each catgeory-wrap.